# Conditional Formula leveraging checkbox (Error: Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'OR()'. Expected Boolean, received Text)

Tags: formula

Trying to figure out how to best implement this.  I am trying to add in a condition to show a value if a checkbox is check versus showing a value if it isn't.  Keep in mind that I have more picklists to add after this, so I would have a "," after customer and add the next condition.  I keep getting this error:
Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'OR()'. Expected Boolean, received Text

Thoughts??

```
IF(
OR(
ISPICKVAL(Picklist1, "Customer"),
ISPICKVAL(Picklist2, "Customer"),
ISPICKVAL(Picklist3, "Customer"),
ISPICKVAL(Picklist4, "Customer"),
ISPICKVAL(Picklist5, "Customer"),
AND(Checkbox_Verify__c, NOT(Checkbox_Override__c)), "Not A Customer", ""),
"Customer", "")
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to catch these issues if you indent everything.

```
IF(
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Picklist1, "Customer"), <-- Condition (Boolean)
        ISPICKVAL(Picklist2, "Customer"), <-- Condition (Boolean)
        ISPICKVAL(Picklist3, "Customer"), <-- Condition (Boolean)
        ISPICKVAL(Picklist4, "Customer"), <-- Condition (Boolean)
        ISPICKVAL(Picklist5, "Customer"), <-- Condition (Boolean)
        AND(                              <-- Condition (Boolean)
            Checkbox_Verify__c,           <-- Condition (Boolean)
            NOT(Checkbox_Override__c)     <-- Condition (Boolean)
        ),                                <-- 
        "Not A Customer",                 <-- Text (here's your problem)
        ""),                              <-- Text (here's your problem)
    "Customer",
    ""
)
```

What you really wanted was:

```
IF(
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(...),
        ISPICKVAL(...),
        ISPICKVAL(...),
        ISPICKVAL(...),
        ISPICKVAL(...),
        ISPICKVAL(...),
        AND(...)
    ),
    "Customer",
    "Not A Customer"
)
```

Comment: Hi @adrianlarson yes, that if I have a few more IF(PICKVAL conditions to add, I cannot close out the formula.  What is the best what to continue this formula to include 3-4 more IF(OR(ISPICKVAL conditions with different values?  Think of what you provided me X 4 more in one formula with different values (for True and False).  Thanks!!!!!